# FCM_SENDER_ID or FCM_SERVER_KEY are invalid in laravel/brozot

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to FCM in laravel 5.2.

I am following this tutorial [click here](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM). But I am not able to send push notification. I have change the server and sender key in config/fcm.php but still it is  throwing the error "FCM_SENDER_ID or FCM_SERVER_KEY are invalid".

Here I am using Api key as my server key and project number as sender Id.

```
        try {
    $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
    $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

    $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder('my title');
    $notificationBuilder->setBody('Hello world')
                        ->setSound('default');

    $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
    $dataBuilder->addData(['a_data' => 'my_data']);

    $option = $optionBuilder->build();
    $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
    $data = $dataBuilder->build();

    $token = "...";

    $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);
    print_r($downstreamResponse);die();

    $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
    $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
    $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

    //return Array - you must remove all this tokens in your database
    $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete(); 

    //return Array (key : oldToken, value : new token - you must change the token in your database )
    $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify(); 

    //return Array - you should try to resend the message to the tokens in the array
    $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry();
}
    catch (\Exception $e) {
return $e->getMessage();
```

}

And my config/fcm.php

```
return [
'driver' => env('FCM_PROTOCOL', 'http'),
'log_enabled' => true,

'http' => [
    'server_key' => env('FCM_SERVER_KEY', '...'),
    'sender_id' => env('FCM_SENDER_ID', '....'),
    'server_send_url' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    'server_group_url' => 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
    'timeout' => 30.0, // in second
],
```

];

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mohammad. Are you positive that you are using the correct ***Server Key*** and not the ***Web API Key***?

Comment: I am using the Web Api key under project->project setting as my server key.

Comment: I see. For FCM, you should only use the **Server Key** under Project > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'll go ahead and add in an answer.

Comment: yeah sure my friend...Cool..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FCM_SENDER_ID or FCM_SERVER_KEY are invalid` is pertaining to a misused credential, in this case is the `FCM_SERVER_KEY`.

When using FCM, you should only use the ***Server Key*** for Authorization, which is seen in your Firebase Console > Project > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging tab.

Answer (score 5):

put those two parameters in the bottom of .env file just like that ...

```
FCM_SERVER_KEY=AAAAAAhDK2...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

and

```
FCM_SENDER_ID=358248592342
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the incorrect FCM_SERVER_KEY

You have to go

Project -> Configuration -> Cloud Messaging -> **Legacy Server Key**